# How can I fix a Navbar at top of page and have it remain there while page scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

When I use...

```
<div id="stay">
<%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
</div>

#stay ul.TabNav {
     background: #FFFFFF;
     border-bottom:solid 2px #00E5EE;
     padding:0 0px;
     font-size:13px;
     overflow:hidden;
     background:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg,#FAFAFA, #FFF);
     background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FAFAFA), to(#FFF));
     position:relative;
     top:0px;
}
```

... its fixed perfectly at top..

And I'd like to have it stay at top so when page scrolls down, it stays at the top and appears like its floating down with the page as it scrolls.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not giving an example so it's hard to tell. I can say that you should be selecting your nav element more specifically, i.e. div#navbar rather than just div.

Comment: you need to give us more than just that line of code if you want help

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed; top: 0;` and be sure your html has a doctype

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look into this, and use some jquery to make it stay

Heres a tutorial to get you started

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/